# Twitter Get user timeline

Tags: c#, widget

The aim is to type in a username and then return the users twitter feed and then save this on a website.

I have created a widget on twitter using a twitter account and my idea was to copy the widget text and then when the user populated the form with the Twitter username they wanted to view I would just swap out the username.

But unfortunately I am unable to do this because of the data-widget-id that is generated this seems to be unique to the user I have created.

```
    <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/**USERNAME**" data-widget-id="**WIDGET ID**">Tweets by</a>
            <script>!function (d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (!d.getElementById(id)) { js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = "//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); } }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Any ideas on the best way to achieve this I have looked at oauthentication but I don't see why I need to authenticate to view a users timeline as I don't users to log in to view a timeline.